# Best way to check if a dir is empty whith php

Tags: php

Is there a better way to check if a dir is empty than parsing it?

Comment: How do you parse a directory? How do you currently check if a directory is empty? (And why are all answers downvoted here?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't think so. Shortest/quickest way I can think of is the following, which should work as far as I can see.

```
function dir_is_empty($path)
{
    $empty = true;
    $dir = opendir($path); 
    while($file = readdir($dir)) 
    {
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
        {
            $empty = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    return $empty;
}
```

This should only go through a maximum of 3 files. The two `.` and `..` and potentially whatever comes next. If something comes next, it's not empty, and if not, well then it's empty.

Comment: @Jon, Why? Not saying it isn't; it might be; just curious as to why.

Answer (score -1):

Not really, but you can try to delete it. If it fails, its not empty (or you just can't delete it ;))

```
function dirIsEmpty ($dir) {
  return rmdir($dir) && mkdir($dir);
}
```

Update:

It seems, that the answer, that takes the condition "without parsing" into account, doesn't find much friends ;)

```
function dirIsEmpty ($dir) {
  return count(glob("$dir/**/*")) === 0:
}
```

Note, that this assumes, that the directory and every subdirectory doesn't contain any hidden file (starting with a single `.`).

Comment: Trying to delete something to know if it's empty feels dirty.... I may be wrong though. (And permissions do matter as you state it)

Comment: @Oktopus: Its not the cleanest solution, but in my opinion its the only one, that doesn't require to iterate over the directories content (which as far as I understand not wanted by the op). My "main answer" to the question "Is there a better solution" is "Not really" ;)

Comment: Assuming the directory doesn't contain any hidden files... isn't that a bit risky? If it does contain hidden files, it isn't really empty, is it?

Comment: It may be risky, if you dont know enough about the directory. For example you have an upload directory and no application put files in it with a starting `.`. In this case -- because you know the directory and its content well -- you can safely assume, that it doesn't contain hidden files.